# How to add babel translations to cleveref-based cross-references to my custom floating environment?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, babel, languages, cleveref

I created a custom float environment, but my translations of the labels for use with `cleveref` are not working:

```
\cref@addlanguagedefs{brazilian}{%
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \Crefname@preamble{frime}{quadro}{quadros}
        \Crefname@preamble{frime}{Quadro}{Quadros}
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine with standard "objects" (such as `figure` and `lstlisting`) as shown below:

[image]

How can I correctly add `brazilian` translations for the labels used by cleveref-based cross-references for `frime`-type floats?

```
\documentclass[brazilian,12pt]{memoir}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english,main=brazil]{babel}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[brazilian]{cleveref}

\def\frimesname{Frame}
\def\listoffrimesname{List of Frames}

\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loq,placement={!hbtp},name=\frimesname,
within=chapter,listname=\listoffrimesname]{frime}

\crefname{frime}{frame}{frames}
\Crefname{frime}{Frame}{Frames}

\makeatletter

\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\frimesname}{Quadro}}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\listoffrimesname}{Lista de Quadros}}

\cref@addlanguagedefs{brazilian}{%
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \Crefname@preamble{frime}{quadro}{quadros}
        \Crefname@preamble{frime}{Quadro}{Quadros}
    }
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Cref figure \Cref{figuree}

autoref figure \autoref{figuree}

Cref frame \Cref{framee}

autoref frame \autoref{framee}

Cref listing \Cref{listingg}

autoref listing \autoref{listingg}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \caption{Opis}
    \label{figuree}
    \includegraphics{latex.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{frime}[h]
    \caption{Stuff.}
    \label{framee}
    Contents.
\end{frime}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Think},label={listingg}]
# If the body of the namespace is longer than this
# number, it won't be indented. Requires
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you load the `babel` package with the options `english` and `main=brazil`, but load the `cleveref` package with the option `brazilian`, I suggest you replace

```
\makeatletter    
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\frimesname}{Quadro}}
\addto\captionsbrazil{\renewcommand{\listoffrimesname}{Lista de Quadros}}

\cref@addlanguagedefs{brazilian}{%
    \AtBeginDocument{%
        \Crefname@preamble{frime}{quadro}{quadros}
        \Crefname@preamble{frime}{Quadro}{Quadros}
    }
}    
\makeatother
```

with

```
\addto\captionsbrazil{%
    \renewcommand{\frimesname}{Quadro}
    \renewcommand{\listoffrimesname}{Lista de Quadros}
    \crefname{frime}{quadro}{quadros}
    \Crefname{frime}{Quadro}{Quadros}
}
```

---

A full MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[brazilian,12pt,demo]{memoir} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{newfloat}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[english,main=brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[brazilian]{cleveref}

\def\frimesname{Frame}
\def\listoffrimesname{List of Frames}    
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[fileext=loq,placement={!hbtp},name=\frimesname,
    within=chapter,listname=\listoffrimesname]{frime}

\crefname{frime}{frame}{frames}
\Crefname{frime}{Frame}{Frames}

%% new:
\addto\captionsbrazil{%
    \renewcommand{\frimesname}{Quadro}
    \renewcommand{\listoffrimesname}{Lista de Quadros}
    \crefname{frime}{quadro}{quadros}
    \Crefname{frime}{Quadro}{Quadros}
    \def\lstlistingautorefname{Listagem} % optional
}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{chapter}{2} % just for this example

Cref figure: \Cref{figuree}

autoref figure: \autoref{figuree}

Cref frame: \Cref{framee}

autoref frame: \autoref{framee}

Cref listing: \Cref{listingg}

autoref listing: \autoref{listingg}


\listoffrimes
\bigskip\hrule

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Opis}
    \label{figuree}
    \includegraphics{latex.png}
\end{figure}

\begin{frime}[h]
    \centering
    \caption{Stuff.}
    \label{framee}
    Contents.
\end{frime}

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={Think},label={listingg}]
# If the body of the namespace is longer than this
# number, it won't be indented. Requires ...
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This thing was getting me crazy!